# Rust: return generic variable

Tags: function, generics, rust, enums

Is it possible in Rust to return generic type as [collect()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) does?. For example: I have this function

```
pub fn chunk<T>(&self, typ: ChunkType) -> &Option<T> {
        match typ {
            PLTE => (),
            GAMA => (),
            CHRM => (),
            SRGB => (),
            ICCP => (),
            TEXT => (),
            ZTXT => (),
            ITXT => (),
            BKGD => (),
            PHYS => (),
            SBIT => (),
            SPLT => (),
            HIST => (),
            TIME => (),
            IHDR => &self.IHDR,
            TRNS => (),
        }
    }
```

and Enum

```
enum ChunkType {
    PLTE,
    GAMA,
    CHRM,
    SRGB,
    ICCP,
    TEXT,
    ZTXT,
    ITXT,
    BKGD,
    PHYS,
    SBIT,
    SPLT,
    HIST,
    TIME,
    IHDR,
    TRNS,
}
```

Can I return specific struct field specified by typ argument in function so that I don't need to write every function for each field? Like that:

```
let chnk: &Option<IHDR_t> = img.chunk(ChunkType::IHDR);
```

Comment: Sadly you can't. At least not with an enum value. The content if `typ` is known at *runtime*, while the return type has to be known at *compile time*. It is possible if you would convert the `enum` into `struct`/`trait`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is kinda right, you could do it like that. *BUT* you then have to `match` or `if let` the result of your `chunk` method.

If you convert your `enum` to an enum-like `trait`/`struct` construct, you can derive the return type automatically:

```rust
fn main() {
    let img = Img {
        hdr: IHDR,
        txt: ITXT,
    };

    // No type annotation needed
    // - hdr is of type &IHDR
    // - txt is of type &ITXT
    let hdr = img.chunk::<HDR>();
    let txt = img.chunk::<TXT>();
}

// The actual data
struct IHDR;
struct ITXT;

// The image holding the data
struct Img {
    hdr: IHDR,
    txt: ITXT,
}

impl Img {
    pub fn chunk<C: ChunkType>(&self) -> &C::Data {
        C::from_img(&self)
    }
}

// The enum-like trait
trait ChunkType {
    type Data;
    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self::Data;
}

// The enum-member like structs
struct HDR;
struct TXT;

impl ChunkType for HDR {
    type Data = IHDR;

    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self::Data {
        &img.hdr
    }
}

impl ChunkType for TXT {
    type Data = ITXT;

    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self::Data {
        &img.txt
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have many types, you could put all of that in a macro:

```rust
fn main() {
    let img = Img {
        hdr: IHDR,
        txt: ITXT,
    };

    // No type annotation needed
    // - hdr is of type &IHDR
    // - txt is of type &ITXT
    let hdr = img.chunk::<HDR>();
    let txt = img.chunk::<TXT>();
}

// The actual data
struct IHDR;
struct ITXT;

// The image holding the data
struct Img {
    hdr: IHDR,
    txt: ITXT,
}

impl Img {
    pub fn chunk<C: ChunkType>(&self) -> &C::Data {
        C::from_img(&self)
    }
}

// The enum-like trait
trait ChunkType {
    type Data;
    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self::Data;
}

macro_rules! img_data_member {
    ($datatype: ident, $enumtype: ident, $imgmember: ident) => {
        struct $enumtype;
        impl ChunkType for $enumtype {
            type Data = $datatype;
            fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self::Data {
                &img.$imgmember
            }
        }
    };
}

img_data_member!(IHDR, HDR, hdr);
img_data_member!(ITXT, TXT, txt);
// ...
```

Or even further, you could skip the quasi-enum type directly and derive the getter method from the return type:

```rust
fn main() {
    let img = Img {
        hdr: IHDR,
        txt: ITXT,
    };

    // No generic annotation needed.
    // What `.chunk` does is derived from the output type
    let hdr: &IHDR = img.chunk();
    let txt: &ITXT = img.chunk();
}

// The actual data
struct IHDR;
struct ITXT;

// The image holding the data
struct Img {
    hdr: IHDR,
    txt: ITXT,
}

impl Img {
    pub fn chunk<C: ChunkType>(&self) -> &C {
        C::from_img(&self)
    }
}

// The enum-like trait
trait ChunkType {
    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self;
}

macro_rules! img_data_member {
    ($datatype: ident, $imgmember: ident) => {
        impl ChunkType for $datatype {
            fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self {
                &img.$imgmember
            }
        }
    };
}

img_data_member!(IHDR, hdr);
img_data_member!(ITXT, txt);
// ...
```

Which one you use is of course up to you and which API you want to expose.

### Explanation

The idea in this last example is that if you have a function `fn chunk<C: ChunkType>(&self) -> &C`, then Rust is smart enough to figure out what `C` should be by backpropagating the type from the variable you assing the return value into, like `let hdr: &IHDR = img.chunk()`.

From there, it's kinda straight forward. All your types that `img.chunk()` can return must be somehow derivable from `Img`, so I introduced a `trait ChunkType` that has the capability to borrow itself from `Img` (via the `from_img` function).

Every chunk type then has to `impl` this trait.
As you have a bunch of traits, I wrote a macro to reduce code duplication.

Macros are not that hard. Let's disect this macro:

```rust
macro_rules! img_data_member {
    ($datatype: ident, $imgmember: ident) => {
        impl ChunkType for $datatype {
            fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self {
                &img.$imgmember
            }
        }
    };
}
```

- `macro_rules! img_data_member { ... }`:
  This defines the name of the macro, in this case `img_data_member`.
- `($datatype: ident, $imgmember: ident) => { ... }`:
  This defines a macro replacement rule. A macro can have several rules. Rules always contain the *input*, in this case `($datatype: ident, $imgmember: ident)`, and the output, here in the `{ ... }`. This means that every `img_data_member!(A, a)` will be replaced with whatever is in the `{ ... }`, with `A` and `a` both being from the type `ident` (= identifier). `A` becomes the `$datatype` and `a` becomes the `$imgmember`.

The entire rest is more-or-less just a simple replacement:

```rust
img_data_member!(A, a);
```

will be replaced with

```rust
impl ChunkType for A {
    fn from_img(img: &Img) -> &Self {
        &img.a
    }
}
```

The cool thing about Rust macros is that the compiler is actually aware of what happens. So you get real, helpful error messages instead of the page long nonsense that C++ compilers used to output.

For example:

```rust
img_data_member!(IHDR, hdr2);
```

Produces the following error:

```
error[E0609]: no field `hdr2` on type `&Img`
  --> src/main.rs:44:24
   |
44 | img_data_member!(IHDR, hdr2);
   |                        ^^^^ help: a field with a similar name exists: `hdr`
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I wrapped everything in ADT Enum:

```
enum ChunkType<'a> {
    PLTE(&'a Option<PLTE_t>),
    GAMA(&'a Option<gAMA_t>),
    CHRM(&'a Option<cHRM_t>),
    SRGB(&'a Option<sRGB_t>),
    ICCP(&'a Option<iCCP_t>),
    TEXT(&'a Option<tEXt_t>),
    ZTXT(&'a Option<zTXt_t>),
    ITXT(&'a Option<iTXt_t>),
    BKGD(&'a Option<bKGD_t>),
    PHYS(&'a Option<pHYs_t>),
    SBIT(&'a Option<sBIT_t>),
    SPLT(&'a Option<sPLT_t>),
    HIST(&'a Option<hIST_t>),
    TIME(&'a Option<tIME_t>),
    IHDR(&'a Option<IHDR_t>),
    TRNS(&'a Option<tRNS_t>),
}
```

and in method

```
pub fn chunk(&self, typ: &str) -> ChunkType {
        match typ {
            "ihdr" => ChunkType::IHDR(&self.IHDR),
            "plte" => ChunkType::PLTE(&self.PLTE),
            "gama" => ChunkType::GAMA(&self.gAMA),
            "chrm" => ChunkType::CHRM(&self.cHRM),
            "srgb" => ChunkType::SRGB(&self.sRGB),
            "iccp" => ChunkType::ICCP(&self.iCCP),
            "text" => ChunkType::TEXT(&self.tEXt),
            "ztxt" => ChunkType::ZTXT(&self.zTXt),
            "itxt" => ChunkType::ITXT(&self.iTXt),
            "bkgd" => ChunkType::BKGD(&self.bKGD),
            "phys" => ChunkType::PHYS(&self.pHYs),
            "sbit" => ChunkType::SBIT(&self.sBIT),
            "splt" => ChunkType::SPLT(&self.sPLT),
            "hist" => ChunkType::HIST(&self.hIST),
            "time" => ChunkType::TIME(&self.tIME),
            "trns" => ChunkType::TRNS(&self.tRNS),
            _ => panic!("Undefined type"),
        }
    }
```

after that I can get value wrapped in enum which contains Option, and after all those manipulations finally get the value

Comment: In that case I must have misunderstood your question. There was definitely context missing. Especially because magically your `typ` variable changed its type to `&str`.

Comment: yep, I changed it, because if I pass it to the function, it asks for type inside, for example, ChunkType::IHDR(_) (I needed to pass ChunkType::IHDR(&None), after this compiler was nice, but it looks kinda ugly), so I decided to explicitly pass it as str

Comment: Using your response, I think I now understand your underlying problem better. Maybe my answer gives you an idea of how else you could solve that problem.